# Google Maps marker cut in half internet explorer

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, google-maps-markers

I'm having a weird problem with my google maps marker icons in internet explorer.   All my markers are showing up cut in half doubled and shifted over 50 %.

[image: http://imgur.com/bPmLC]

that is using the demo code from google.   So it must be something weird i'm doing elsewhere with styles or jquery, but i don't know what.    Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: recently i have odd behaviors with my google map demos on jsfiddle also.  seems to me the rendering doesn't refresh very well.  so, what i did is after applying changes to map i "refresh it" with `map.setCenter(<new latlng>);` and then re-zoom.  Furthermore, the issue seems deal with any overlay on the map.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue.
The problem being that each marker icon inherited a margin>0, I solved the issue by setting the margin to zero for all img in the map div.

```
<style type="text/css">
   #map_canvas img {
       margin: 0px
   }
</style>
```

Comment: This turned out to be the issue for me too. The API generates different elements for Firefox and Chrome, so you can't use Firebug. To find out what style is giving you trouble in IE, use the IE7 browser mode, and be sure to hit the refresh button in the Developer Tools toolbar after the map loads. That will refresh the DOM and let you select the marker image to inspect it. Use the Trace Styles pane to find the offending style.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is interesting, in that it was happening with the default markers as well. I described a similar issue for custom markers in a blog post on Feb 2012:
http://www.gutensite.com/Google-Maps-Custom-Markers-Cut-Off-By-Canvas-Tiles

We were having problems with Google Maps API Version 3.8 (newer than several others who proposed solutions here). The custom markers would be cut off, while the default markers were not. We discovered that this was caused by the new Canvas tiles that are used to optimize how Google Maps display. If you inspect elements, you can see that the markers are actually tile layers.

If we turned off 'optimized' (see code below) the markers displayed correctly! So it appears to be related to the optimization code.

```
var point = new google.maps.Marker({
'position': position,
'map': this.options.map.construct,  
'icon': marker_data.custom_icon,    
'title': marker_data.title, 
'optimized': false
});
```

I have not confirmed whether this issue has been fixed by Google since then or not, or if there is a better solution.

Others have suggested that if you parseInt() the markers' width and height, it solved their problem.

See linked article for pictures. Stackoverflow won't let me include them because I don't have enough reputation points :-\

Comment: awesome solution. that solved my problem. I only had to add `optimizeWaypoints: false,` to my request too

Comment: I have the same problem. The answer is now 4 years old but I thought it still works. I do not say it is not working but in my case it has no effect. I had to set the `optimized` to `true` to solve the problem. If `optimized` is not used or set to `false` I have half markers, regardless if it is the basic Google Maps ones or custom ones. I have to set explicitly to `true` to solve the problem.

Comment: Weirdly, my pins were appearing perfectly for around 1.5 years without using this attribute. Then, all of a sudden, they were being cropped. I tried all sorts of 'fixes' to no avail, then stumbled across this and tried it, and it fixed it. So bizarre, but seriously, thank you so much for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem by using a stable version of the api like...

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false

instead of the nightly dev build...(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false)

Comment: This fixed the IE7 specific problem I was having. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I managed to fix this issue by putting in the link as above, but it's suddenly started breaking again. Anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, (i used custom marker images, and they were shifted by 1px left and bottom in IE7-8)

This code solved the problem:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style>
    div#map img{
      margin-top: -1px;
      margin-left: -1px;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Where `map` is the id of the google map api container div.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; I had to set both the margin and the padding to 0:

```
#map img {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `#map_canvas img { margin: 0px; }` solution above, but it only half worked. I changed it to `#map_canvas img { margin: -5px; }` and applied to the IE7 & IE8 stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt around the values made it for me

```
new google.maps.Size(parseInt(width), parseInt(height))
new google.maps.Point(parseInt(width)/2, parseInt(height))
```