# Google Maps v3 Marker on Android devices are broken

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

I have a problem with GM markers on android devices...
[image: Markers on android devices]

On desktop or iOS markers looks good... What I do wrong?

Url to [site](http://www.inpro.com.pl/chmielna-park/lokalizacja)

Comment: Are you looking at the map through Chrome?  I'm on Chrome 31, Android 4.4.0 and I have a map with similar markers that look fine.

Comment: Hi. I updated my post with url to site where this problem occurs.

Comment: I do see it too, so it is not just you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5874336/1379237) answer helped me deal with it...

Setting margin to 0 fixed the problem...

```
<style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas img {
        margin: 0px;
    }
</style>
```